# Online average in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I get across [this article](https://dev.to/nestedsoftware/calculating-a-moving-average-on-streaming-data-5a7k) about online average computation and I would like to translate this code into Haskell. My naive idea was to use semigroups:

```
import Data.Semigroup

newtype MovingAverage = MovingAverage { getMovingAverage :: Float }

instance Semigroup MovingAverage where
  (MovingAverage a) <> (MovingAverage b) = MovingAverage (a+(a-b)*recip n) -- Variable not in scope: n
```

However, semigroups don't remember their position, so thus it's not possible to know value `n`.

**So my question is:** What's the most elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single Float is not enough to maintain a moving average, so your data type will have to hold more than a single Float. One obvious approach would be to define a data type with two fields, the average and a count of how many items it represents:

```
data MovingAverage = MovingAverage Int Float
```

Then it is easy to combine two MovingAverage values using their respective averages and item counts:

```
instance SemiGroup MovingAverage where
  (MovingAverage n x) <> (MovingAverage m y) = -- ...
```

I've left the implementation blank because there are actually two reasonable implementations: you could

1. Maintain the sum and a divisor, computing the actual average only when demanded;
2. Maintain the average and a multiplier, refactoring every time you combine averages

(1) will be cheaper if you combine averages more often than you look at them (since adding is cheaper than dividing and multiplying), but (2) will be cheaper if you query the same average many times, because it avoids dividing every time you query.

In practice I would usually expect (1) to be the simplest approach, and perform reasonably well for normal workloads. There's an improvement to (1) you could try, which is probably overkill for just moving averages but could make sense if you try to apply this pattern to more expensive computations.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Data.Semigroup

data MovingAverage = MovingAverage { sum :: !Float,
                                     count :: !Int,
                                     getAverage :: Float
                                   }

mkAverage :: Float -> MovingAverage
mkAverage x = MovingAverage x 1 x

instance Semigroup MovingAverage where
  (MovingAverage x n _) <> (MovingAverage y m _) = MovingAverage quot div (quot / fromIntegral div)
    where quot = x + y
          div = n + m
```

This is the same as (1), except that we include a field for caching the result of the division, which is written but never read. So if a client calls `getAverage` multiple times on the same value, only one division is performed; or if they never call it, then no division is needed at all, and we can work just with nice cheap sums. The downside is that your record is larger, and you spend time allocating a lot of thunks that nobody ever looks at. As I said, you would probably only do this to cache a more expensive query, where you are also unsure whether it will be updated more often or queried more often.

Example usage:

```
*Main Data.Semigroup> getAverage $ mkAverage 13 <> stimes 9 (mkAverage 3)
4.0
```